# Mirror servers lista, correct a translation

Tags: update-manager, language-support, mirrors, internationalization, localization

when using Ubuntu in Occitan the country on the mirror list is not correct for the United States, it shows "France", and France is correctly translated into "França".
I couln't find where to correct this =/
Here some screenshot showing Ubuntu in English with correct name and then in Occitan.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

https://salsa.debian.org/iso-codes-team/iso-codes/-/blob/main/iso_3166-1/oc.po#L1625

So I'd suggest that you change it via a merge request to Debian's iso-codes repo.

*Edit:*

Better to do it via Weblate:

https://hosted.weblate.org/projects/iso-codes/iso-3166-1/oc/

Comment: Many thanks! I've changed it upstream! Now waiting for it to waterfal ^^

Comment: @Quentin: I see the change made it to the Debian repo instantly. In other words it will make it to Ubuntu in connection with next package update at Debian.